# Why are pilot waves in quantum mechanics said to be Faraday waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

De Broglie proposed a pilot wave in connection with quantum mechanics. He was more or less forced to abandon this wave in favor of the Copenhagen view. Bohm furthered his approach in the fifties but he also met resistance. Maybe because of his early communist sympathies. And maybe these same sympathies didn't make him succomb to the Copenhagen view.

When I sat with my feet in an electric foot bath I noticed that the water surface surrounding my feet exhibited a standing wave pattern. The smaller the wavelengths were the stabler it got. I could move my feet around without disturbing the pattern at a certain high frequency point. I observed all kinds of motions when I changed the vibrating frequency. Things got out of hand when my girfriend added too much soap...

By accident I learned that what I saw were Faraday waves. We can read:

> The Faraday wave and its wavelength is analogous to the de Broglie wave with the de Broglie wavelength in De Broglie–Bohm theory in the field of quantum mechanics.

I dont get this. I can see that if you put a small object on the waving surface, the object will stay put in crests and it will move if the wave moves. But I see no erratic behavior of the small mass. Then why is it said that de Broglie (Bohm) waves are Faraday waves? Did Faraday have some hidden structure view on the waves named after him?

Comment: The analogy appears to have been proposed by the MIT Physicist John Bush in his 2015 paper [The new wave of pilot-wave theory](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282806859_The_new_wave_of_pilot-wave_theory), where he writes *The Faraday wavelength*
$\lambda_F$ *in the fluid system plays the role of the de Broglie
wavelength* $\lambda_B$ *for the orbiting charged particle*.